# How to design the class structure instead of using a big enum

Tags: c#, oop, uml

My problem is the following: I have products, which require other products in order to be produced. For example, to make a boat, you need X timber and Y iron. I have to represent somehow both the dependencies and the products. I need to be able to show how much timber there is in some storage and how much timber I need to build a boat.

So my first thought was to create a big enum `Products`, and then I could build dictionaries like `Dictionary<Products, int> RequiredProducts` or `Dictionary<Products, int> StoredProducts`. However, there can be a lot of products and it feels like it's a bad design to make an enum with about 50 fields. And also, I may need more information about each product, for example its graphical representation, required technology and so on.

It would be much better to use some class hierarchy, but if I make an abstract class Product, and then derive from it, how would I represent the required products? `Dictionary<Product, int>` won't do, since now I'd require an instance of a Product to add something to the dictionary. The language I use is C#.

Comment: Maybe you can use a factory pattern here.

Comment: Actually I'm leaning towards using reflection, and build dictionaries with class names as keys. Still not sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is not very much information provided. But before thinking of code structures you should model the business domain. You could be starting with this model

[image]

which is deduced from the information stated in your question. Just go on with that and create a complete business model. Only then start transforming it into one or more technical model(s).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the problem, I would suggest to just use the same class inside yours. You will have code like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual ICollection<Product> RequiredProducts {get; set;}    
    ...
}
```

If you aren't going to use your RequiredProducts as usual products you can create a separate class for this purpose:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual ICollection<Material> RequiredMaterials {get; set;}    
    ...
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't solve your problem and I'll try to help you.

**Update:** You can make lightweight proxy class for your Product and fill it with only you need. For instance:

```
public class LightProduct 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So it will be related to the actual product in your database and your memory won't be flooded.

I wouldn't recommend go with the reflection in such case as it will significally slow down performance in this part of your application.

An approach with dictionaries containing names of products might have problems if Product's name has changed while you already have a dictionary filled. I would consider other approaches instead.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to create actual instances of the products - I want to have something like a recipe. I need only the information about how much of X i need to create Y, but I don't want to flood the memory with hundreds of X instances

Comment: So this is basically the approach with a big enum plus a separate class for each field in the enum. Well I fear there's no other solution, however I'll wait a bit and maybe someone will come up with something different.

Comment: Approach with enum has the disadvantage of immutability. After you make your project and compile it you won’t be able to change your enum, hence won’t be able to apply any changes to your products set. And if you are so sure that your products won’t change at all during running of your application you can just make a dictionary of strings and use product names there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe so:

[image class scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufwda.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductRecept = new HashSet<ProductRecept>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductRecept> ProductRecept { get; set; }
} 

public partial class Material
{
    public Material()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public partial class ProductRecept
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public decimal Qu { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
}
```